# Dropdownlist Selected value is not working

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 dropdowns ddl1 and ddl2. When im setting selected value for ddl1 it works,but after setting selected value for ddl2 also changes the value of ddl1.I dont know how but its doing so.

### aspx

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPickup" runat="server" CssClass="tb_date" 

                       >                            
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Dropoff:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDropoff" runat="server" CssClass="tb_date" >
                    </asp:DropDownList>    
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radiobuttonlist1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="radiobuttonlist1_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Day or Longer</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">1/2 Day</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Hourly</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

### code behind

```
protected void radiobuttonlist1_selectedindexchange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(radiobuttonlist1.SelectedValue=="1")
{
     Setddl();
}
}
public void Setddl()
{
if (ddlPickup.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlPickup.Items.Clear();
            }
            if (ddlDropoff.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlDropoff.Items.Clear();
            }
            ListItem li = new ListItem();
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate.Text);
            int day = Convert.ToInt32(date.DayOfWeek);
            long itemid = Convert.ToInt64(ddlRentalItem.SelectedValue);
            if (itemid != 0)
            {
                var dropoff = _objRitems.GetHourlyHourByDay(itemid, day);
                if (dropoff.Count > 0)
                {



                    int stimeh = Convert.ToDateTime(dropoff[0].OpenTime).Hour;
                    int etimeh = Convert.ToDateTime(dropoff[0].CloseTime).Hour;
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dropoff[0].OpenTime);
                    for (int i = 0; i <= (etimeh - stimeh) * 2; i++)
                    {
                        string time = string.Format("{0:t}", dt);
                        li = new ListItem(time, time);
                        ddlPickup.Items.Add(li);
                        ddlDropoff.Items.Add(li);
                        dt = dt.AddMinutes(30);
                    }
                    ddlPickup.DataBind();
                    ddlDropoff.DataBind();
ddlPickup.SelectedValue=Request.QueryString["droptime"].ToString();
ddlDropoff.SelectedValue=Request.QueryString["droptime"].ToString();
//as soon as ddlDropoff SelectedValue assigns ddlPickup.SelectedValue changes to ddlDropoff.SelectedValue..Very Weird!!!
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
}
```

Comment: Post some source code or else it will be impossible to help you

Comment: @incomplete - is there server side selectedIndex chnaged or Javascript events? can you post these please

Comment: @incomplete - If you have handled the selected index change event for ddl2 on server side then ddl1 selected item will change also due to the post back.

Comment: But i havnt set autopostback to true for any ddl, and there is only one ondatabount event for two ddl and its firing right after ddl.databind()

Comment: @incomplete - Please include the complete codebehind contents in your question.

Comment: sorry about previous incomplete code, i was searching searching whole day for this. dont know where im going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write your dropdown code in below if condition.

if(!isPostBack)
{

}

Comment: ok then just click on dropdown smart tag and uncheck Enable Auto postback

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `ddlPickup_DataBound`. Rely on the ViewState implicit in dropdown lists to repopulate the selected value. The ondatabound methods are unnecessary in this case.

Also you only need to bind the dropdowns once so on `Page.IsPostBack` - like the other poster has said

This would be the more standard way to deal with drop downs i.e.

1. Bind once
2. SelectedValue persists in after postbacks. No need for special work here

The way you are doing it - the databound will fire on each page load (after each dropdown if autopostback is true). The both dropdowns will repopulate every time - depending what yor have got in your `Request` collection. This isn't what you intend i assume and would account for the strange behaviour.

**EDIT:**

Just to be really clear this is the pattern that should be followed

**Markup**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPickup" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDropoff" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="selectedIndexEvent"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
       BindDropDownLists();    
   }
}

protected void ddl2_selectedindexchange(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    //.. legit - do whatever is needed but don't reset selected value 
}

protected void radiobuttonlist1_selectedindexchange(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
{
      BindDropDownLists();    
      SetInitialDropDownValues();
}
```

No ondatanound is needed

Comment: @incomplete. The reason you are only seeing this problem with ddl2 is that is the only one with OnSelectedIndexChanged="radiobuttonlist1_SelectedIndexChanged". Do you need this? Remove and see if that resolves. But only bind the controls once and don't explicitly set selectedValue. Just remove the ondatabound event from the markup. It's doing you no good

Comment: tried..no luck.. still ddl1 value is automatically changes to same as ddl2 :-( I've edited my previous code to current. Please check and reply..

Comment: @incomplete Are you sure? - ondatabound is still there as is SelectedIndexChanged. I'm referring to your markup

Comment: oops for ondatabound..But selectedindexchange event should be there thats how im databinding those ddls.

Comment: @incomplete. OK I've added in some skeleton code. Honestly - stick to this pattern and you will be find. I think you will have to do a bit of rewritting of your code.